# What are these set operations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to do these math problems:

U=Names of the states in the US

A = States that begin with "a" = {AK, AL, AZ. AR}
B = States that border Mexico = {AZ, CA, NM, TX}
C = States on the Pacific coast = {AL, CA, OR, WA}

```
Find (A union B union C)'

Find (B union C} intersection A

Find (A intersection B) union C
```

Comment: These problems are all made to test and practice your understanding of union ($\cup$) and intersection ($\cap$). Do you know what these two concepts mean?

Comment: Yes,I know that union is what elements are in both sets.While intersection is what both sets have in common.I just don't understand how to do it when they add the parentheses and ' complement.

Comment: Parentheses mean do the operation(s) inside the parentheses first. The result is a new set. That set replaces the parentheses and everything inside them, and then you can do the remaining operations. To take a complement you need to have a universal set of some sort; I'm guessing all 50 states of the U.S.?

Comment: Sorry,the universal set is U=Names of the states in the US.So far,for the first answer I got this: { Ø } second answer: {AZ,AL} third answer: {AZ,AL,CA,OR,WA}.

Comment: The second and third are correct. As for the first one, what is the union of all three sets? Now, are there states in America that aren't in that union (what about NY, SD, and all the others)? Such a state should be in the _complement_ of that union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that $Q^\prime=U\setminus Q$. For example: $\{x:x\text{ is a state that is not VA}\}'$ is $\{\text{VA}\}$, since $U\setminus\{x:x\text{ is a state that is not VA}\}=\{\text{VA}\}$. (Note that $Q\setminus A$ is the elements in $Q$ *not* in $A$.)

So, the first problem stands as thus:

$$U\setminus(A\cup B\cup C).$$

Now, when they throw parenthesis in, you must evaluate them first. For example, let $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{3,4,5\}$, $C=\{5,6,7\}$. So, $(B\cup C)\cap A=\{3,4,5,6,7\}\cap\{1,2,3\}=\{3\}$. The third problem follows the same schematic.

Does this clarify your problems?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correct,but for the first one I got:{ Ø } Second answer: {AZ,AL} Third answer: {AZ,AL,CA,OR,WA}.

Comment: @Samantha Your first answer is incorrect. Consider that it has $\text{VA}\in(1)$. (Also, if you wish to refer to the empty or null set, use $\varnothing$ or $\{\}$; $\{\varnothing\}$ is a set with the empty set inside of it.) May I wonder as to how you obtained the solution? Perhaps I can help you there.

Your second and third answers are correct.